# Python Print Socket used to connect to server

Tags: python, sockets

What I am trying to do is a little bit complicated to explain but hopefuly this explanation makes sense and someone will be able to help

I have a python socket client and server. Everything works fine, and for development purposes I have made the server also print a message when a new client connects. I have noticed the server will output something like:

```
New connection on 127.0.0.1:26386
```

The  server runs on port 8888. Anyway, I noticed that the client port is different for every client.

```
New connection on 127.0.0.1:26397
New connection on 127.0.0.1:26398
```

And so on. What I would like is very simple: I want the client to print the port its using to connect to the server. So client 1 would print 26386 as seen above. The next one 26397 and 26398 and so on.

How can I do this? I understand the explanation might be a bit weird, just comment if you want me to clarify anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to get the local address of the socket, i.e. the source IP address and port. This can be done with [socket.getsockname](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.getsockname) and similar [socket.getpeername](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.getpeername) can be used to get the target IP address and port. I.e. in your example you would get:

```
# on the client side
print(socket_to_server.getsockname())   # ->  (127.0.0.1,26386)
print(socket_to_server.getpeername())   # ->  (127.0.0.1, 8888)

# on the server side
print(socket_from_client.getsockname()) # ->  (127.0.0.1, 8888)
print(socket_from_client.getpeername()) # ->  (127.0.0.1,26386)
```